# Exponentiation with negative base

Tags: r, nan, exponentiation

So, the R expression and its output is as follows:

```
> (4-7)^1.3
[1] NaN
```

Any ideas how to solve this in R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is a complex number, so you need to give it a complex argument:

```
> (4-7+0i)^1.3
[1] -2.451751-3.374545i
```

but remember this is only one root...

Answer (score 6):

I quote from Wikipedia, especially the bold text (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation):

> The IEEE 754-2008 floating point standard is used in the design of most > floating point libraries. It recommends a number of different functions for computing a power:[19]
>
> - pow treats 00 as 1. This is the oldest defined version. If the power is an exact integer the result is the same as for pown, otherwise the result is as for powr (except for some exceptional cases).
> - pown treats 00 as 1. **The power must be an exact integer.** The value is defined for negative bases, e.g. pown(−3,5) is −243.
> - powr treats 00 as NaN (Not-a-Number - undefined). The value is also NaN for cases like powr(−3,2) where the base is less than zero. The value is defined by epower×log(base).

So I think R is showing standard behavior according to international standards.

Comment: Am I totally off base here with my answer (taking into account the other answer)?

Comment: Who knows? R is quite happy with non-integer powers as long as its of a positive number (2^(0.5) gives the positive square root of 2) but once you take non-integer roots of negative numbers there's a chance there will be no real root so it says "NaNaNaNaNa not listening", abbreviated to "NaN".

Comment: I don't think you're off base.  There's not really enough context in the original question. You explain why, @Spacedman is explaining one solution.  Another possibility would be `sign(x)*(abs(x)^b)` (certainly *not* the same mathematically, but maybe useful.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, always ready to learn new things :).

Comment: actually, now that I look at this more carefully (4 years later), it's not quite right -- it's referring to "indeterminate forms" (exponentiating expressions involving infinite values), not real operations with complex results https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN