# R expression results in NaN for no obvious reason

Tags: r, expression, nan, equation

How can it be that the expression

```
> (exp(17.118708 + 4.491715 * -2)/-67.421587)^(-67.421587)
```

results in

```
[1] NaN
```

while

```
> -50.61828^(-67.421587)
```

which should basically have the same outcome, gives me

```
[1] -1.238487e-115
```

This is driving me crazy, I spent hours searching for the Error. "-2", in this case, is a Parameter of the function. I really can't think of a solution. Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I see that when I add brackets

```
> (-50.61828)^(-67.421587)
```

it also results in

```
[1] NaN
```

...but that does not solve my Problem.

Comment: @warmoverflow, you're correct, I've copied the wrong code. I edited the question.

Comment: [HelpLink1](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/8-1-3-NaN-td895638.html) [HelpLink2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437701/how-to-calculate-any-negative-number-to-the-power-of-some-fraction-in-r) [HelpLink3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166988/exponentiation-with-negative-base) Good Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is because of the implementation of `pow` under C99 standard.**

Let alone OP's example: `(-50.61828)^(-67.421587)`, the mathematically justified `(-8)^(1/3) = -2` does not work in R:

```
(-8)^(1/3)
# [1] NaN
```

Quoted from `?"^"`:

```
 Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example
 why ‘(-8)^(1/3)’ is ‘NaN’.  For double inputs, R makes use of IEC
 60559 arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system
 function ‘pow’ for the ‘^’ operator.  The relevant standards
 define the result in many corner cases.  In particular, the result
 in the example above is mandated by the C99 standard.  On many
 Unix-alike systems the command ‘man pow’ gives details of the
 values in a large number of corner cases.
```

I am on Ubuntu LINUX, so can help get relevant part of `man power` printed here:

```
   If x is a finite value less than 0, and y is  a  finite  noninteger,  a
   domain error occurs, and a NaN is returned.
```

Comment: Then why does (-10)^(-60) result in 1e-60?

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed, quite obvious. The function is simply not defined for a specific range.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, `-50.61828^(-67.421587)` is evaluating as `-(50.61828^(-67.421587))`. `(-50.61828)^(-67.421587)` also results in NaN.

Comment: See my edited question, I copied the wrong values, nevertheless, you're right. But why is the outcome still NaN?

Comment: How do you define `x^y` when both `x` and `y` are negative and nonintegral?