# R: Raise to the power -- odd behaviour

Tags: r, negative-number, arithmetic-expressions

This is a brief one, but I am totally puzzled about the following:

> (-1/1000)^2.5
>   [1] NaN
>
> ## However:
>
> -0.001^2.5
>   [1] -3.162278e-08

Can a kind soul illuminate the functioning of R in this case?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38061082/4891738) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19437701/4891738). Note, `-0.001^2.5` is `-(0.001^2.5)`, not `(-0.001)^2.5`

Comment: I should have guessed that someone else had come across the same issue. Thank so much anyway for the reply. Very clear.